# Getting a v-checkbox to work in a v-expansion-panel-header

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a v-expansion-panel-header which contains a v-checkbox. If I click on the checkbox the checkbox does not check/uncheck. Instead the expansion panel opens/closes.  How do I allow the checkbox to work and have the panel only open when the default icon that is supplied is clicked on?

I have tried using @click.stop and @click.native.stop, @click.capture, @change.stop etc on the v-checkbox, but it doesn't work.

```
  <v-expansion-panels>
    <v-expansion-panel>
      <v-expansion-panel-header>
        <v-checkbox v-model="checkbox" label="MyCB" @click.stop />
      </v-expansion-panel-header>
      <v-expansion-panel-content>
        Lorem ipsum dolor.
      </v-expansion-panel-content>
    </v-expansion-panel>
  </v-expansion-panels>
```

Comment: Which version of Vuetify are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest version of Vue and Vuetify

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is that the event is bubbling up from the checkbox to the expansion panel. What you need to do is, when the checkbox is being clicked, pass the event into a function, and cancel the event bubbling.

```
    check: function(e) {
      e.cancelBubble = true;
    }
```

Check the working code [here](https://codepen.io/CodingDeer/pen/ymgWqZ?editors=1010)

Note that, in the example I had wrapped a v-flex around the v-checkbox. This is because the v-checkbox was spanning the whole width of the expansion panel and I think you still want the expansion to work when you click on places that are not close to the checkbox. You can probably find some other ways of preventing full width in CSS but this was just a quick and dirty way to demonstrate the prevent event bubbling solution.

Comment: Very interesting... it works with the latest Firefox (68.0.1) non ESR version, but if I run your example in Firefox (60.8.1 ESR) the check() method never fires...

Comment: Strange! So, clicking on box the checkbox and the checkbox text does't fire the event?

Comment: Correct. I filed a bug report in Vuetify as it seems outside of this solution. I went ahead and accepted your answer since it is most likely the correct way of doing it.